# I want to Add ID when i upload Image in Node Js Server

Tags: android, node.js, api

Hey Everyone I am stucking in between the id and image i want to send id along with my image to Node JS Server, Right now it just send only image through API or android application.

```
var express = require ('express');
const app = express();

var fileupload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileupload());

app.get ("/", (req,res,next) => {
    res.status(200).send("Hello World");
});

app.post("/upload", function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.files);

    const id = req.id;
    const file = req.files.upload;
    console.log("ID"+ id);
    file.mv('./uploads/'+file.name, function(err, result){
        if(err)
            throw err;
        res.send({

            success : true,
            message : "File Uploaded!"
        });


    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Started on port : 3000");
})
```

Comment: `req.id` does not exist; the `Request` object does not have arbitrary properties like that. Please clarify in your question how you're passing the id to the server. If it's a query parameter, use `req.query.id`. If it's part of a multipart form body, use `req.body.id`.

Comment: let me know what changes I need to make to send an ID to the server at the same time as file, so that I can associate that file with a given user ID in the Mongo database that I am using?

Comment: @Areebsiddiqui do you mean a request id not user id, don't you?

Comment: In simple words , Just like a profile picture which is associate  with user id

Comment: If it's a profile picture, the server should already have a login session containing the user id, so it does not need to be sent from the client. Otherwise anyone could change anyone else's profile picture if they just know or guess their user id...

Comment: I agree with @Thomas, let's take a step back and discuss what's the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: What I understand he wants to achieve is that a user logs into his account and tries to upload a file/image or whatever. How do you associate that entity with the user before saving to database. Else the file will have to be saved without knowing who uploaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate a id on the server side upon substitution. This would probably be better than trusting the client with the id unless you have a special need to have the client generate the id.

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

app.post("/upload", function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.files);

    const id = uuid();
    const file = req.files.upload;
    console.log("ID"+ id);
    file.mv('./uploads/'+file.name, function(err, result){
        if(err)
            throw err;
        res.send({

            success : true,
            message : "File Uploaded!"
        });


    });
});
```